# 2 Way SSL for Magento API

Tags: php, openssl

Checked many blogs for 2 way ssl(Mutual Authentication) for magento api's or PHP but did not get end to end implementation details.

**Below is my understanding.**

Lets consider client (sslclient.com) and server (sslserver.com), both will communicate after verifying ssl certificate.
The client will verify server certificate and server will verify the client certificate.

As I checked changes required in apache config and php curl.

**Below are the blogs which I have visited**

- https://dzone.com/articles/implementing-one-way-and-two-way-ssl-mutual-authen
- https://medium.com/@kasunpdh/ssl-handshake-explained-4dabb87cdce
- https://www.scriptjunkie.us/2013/11/adding-easy-ssl-client-authentication-to-any-webapp/
- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6586357/how-to-secure-a-restful-php-web-service-with-ssl-tls-and-or-message-level-securi
- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30615007/php-soap-webservice-call-with-two-way-ssl-authentication
- https://linuxconfig.org/apache-web-server-ssl-authentication
- https://davegebler.com/post/php/mutual-tls-with-apache-and-php

**Below is the business logic**

- Enable 2way ssl
- Client can access the server api's after certificate validation

  - Ex: This is e commerce website and there are api's called order placement, product and category etc..
- Server will send the order status notification to client when the order is fulfilled.

**Below are the questions.**

- What are the changes required in PHP and apache.
- What are the certificates, the client should pass to the server.
- What are the certificates, the server should pass to the client.

If anyone knows end to end implementation, please share your input.

Comment: What exactly is your question? I can't find a single question in your post

Comment: @MechMK1 Updated questions, please have a look

Answer (score 0):

> What are the changes required in PHP and apache.
> What are the certificates, the client should pass to the server.
> What are the certificates, the server should pass to the client.

Your questions are answered in my blog post that you've linked in your question. In particular see the section https://davegebler.com/post/php/mutual-tls-with-apache-and-php#configure-apache-for-mututal-tls

I'm not sure I can break it down any better here than I did there. Perhaps it would help myself or another contributor provide you with better support if you explained which bit you're having trouble with?